# Vertically align a variable-height image in a smaller fixed-height element

Tags: html, css, vertical-alignment

I have the following HTML, which I could change, but would prefer to keep simple as it is.

```
<div class="c">
     <img ...>
</div>
```

The image will be a variable size, and should be centered vertically within the div.  I'm currently using the following CSS:

```
.c {
    width: 40px;
    height: 40px;
    overflow: hidden;
}
.c img {
    width: 40px;
    height: auto;
}
```

I've tried using the table and table-cell method in CSS, but the container expands to fit the image, even with `overflow: hidden`.  I've considered server-side methods, like using `position: relative` with a negative `top` value on the `<img>`, but would prefer not to use any additional server-side processing on the page if I don't have to.  I do not want to use JavaScript, so if that's my only other option, I'll just do it server-side.
I should mention, the image will always be 40x40px or larger.

[This fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/qrSyc/) demonstrates what I was attempting with `display: table`.

Comment: If you don't require the `<img>` node, you can try this: http://jsfiddle.net/qrSyc/2/

Comment: it seem u should use javascript/jquery to do this..

Comment: @Passerby, I would prefer to use that method, but since the images can potentially be larger in both width and height, and `background-size` is not yet well-supported, I preferred using an `<img>` tag.  I suppose I could just center the image both directions, and include a `background-size` for the browsers that support it, if another solution doesn't seem to work better.

Comment: @alanaktion I didn't use `background-size` in my fiddle...only `background-position` is used, and it's supported in even IE.

Comment: @Passerby: I know you used `background-position`, which is what I would be using, but since the images could be wider and taller than the container, I want them to scale to fit it horizontally, then vertically-align.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've decided on a simpler method, that will not scale images on older browsers, but will on newer ones, as well as use much less code.  The HTML can basically just be a `<div>` tag, with this CSS.

```
div.image {
    background: url(IMAGE) center center no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
}
```

The `background-size: cover` will allow CSS3-compliant browser to scale the image to fit the div, while older ones will still center the image, but not scale it.  It's not a perfect solution, but will certainly work for my case.

Answer (score 0):

..............................***[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/qrSyc/3/)***

Hi now used to `vertical-align:top` in your `img tag` **throw** css as like this

```
img {
     vertical-align:top;
}
```

***[Live demo](http://jsfiddle.net/qrSyc/3/)***

Answer (score -1):

Take a look here: http://www.vanseodesign.com/css/vertical-centering/

You can pick the method that you feel most comfortable with.

Comment: Each of these solutions works great for the typical vertical alignment of a div within a larger div, but do not work if the element being vertically aligned is larger than it's container, and is also a dynamic size.